# How do you exchange bitcoin for real money?

Tags: trading

I have been wondering this question for a while now, so I am using NiceHash and my bitcoin address should be going to my bitcoin wallet but I want to know are there any legit sites that give you real money (AUD) in exchange for bitcoin since there is a lot of scam sites that don't actually give you money instead take your bitcoin, so if anyone knows a site that is **NOT** a scam and is legit for exchanging.

(**NOTE**: *I would like to exchange to something like a credit card or PayPal*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To exchange Bitcoin with another currency, you are really selling your bitcoin to someone else in return for "real" money. One popular exchange site is [LocalBitcoins](https://localbitcoins.com/). This site offers many different methods of exchange.

To the best of my knowledge, selling bitcoin using PayPal violates their terms of service, although some sites do offer this.